# trigger automatic postback in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I do not have access to the `<body>` tag because it is in masterpage. 
I want to trigger an automatic postback when the page load as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.onscroll=  __doPostBack("<%= button.ClientID %>", "");
</script>
```

where should I put this code? I get a Not implemented JS error if I place it just before the `</asp:Content>` tag.

Any idea how I should do this ?

PS: I need to trigger that postback because I want to populate an updatepanel when the page loads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have such code and place it anywhere:

```
<% if (!Page.IsPostBack) { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   __doPostBack("<%= button.ClientID %>", "");
}
</script>
<% } %>
```

Assuming you're using C# - if you have VB.NET the syntax will be bit different.

Edit: to avoid using `<%` and `%>` you can have this in the Page_Load of your page:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
   this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "auto_postback", "window.onload = function() { __doPostBack(\"" +  button.ClientID + "\", \"\"); }; ", true);
}
```

Edit II: alternative way with better chance of working is to have such JS code instead:

```
"window.onload = function() { var buttonID = '" +  button.ClientID + "'; alert('ID: ' + buttonID + ', clicking...'); document.getElementById(buttonID).click(); }; "
```

This will hopefully show you the client ID of the button then auto click it. If no luck make sure the ID is correct and really exist in the document and we'll try to find what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using MVC. The compiler does not understand <%. Can I fix this? Thanks again

Comment: @Ryan it's not MVC, it's standard ASP server side code notation that should work in any ASP.NET .aspx page. What error you get exactly?

Comment: your code inserts the code in the page right( thanks), but there is no postback fired when the page loads. Do you know which is th cause? I have a button with id="button", and I want to trigger a postback as if the button would be clicked.

Comment: @Ryan time for debug then.. add `alert(typeof __doPostBack);` in the function - what you see in the alert?

Comment: I get the text: function inside my alert. What should i do?

Comment: works with this. Do you think there may be any problems in some browsers?

Comment: @Ryan it's totally cross browser afaik, however if you'll ever need to use the `onload` event for other things it will conflict with this, so remember to add whatever you need inside the existing function. BTW, tags edited to be more proper to the contents. :)